# Failure at "bundle-install"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to work on a new project on Ubuntu. After cloning the GitHub repo and installing ruby `sudo apt-get install ruby`, y perform

```
bundle install
```

and I get this feedback:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.4) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2) 
Using multi_json (1.7.2) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Installing ffi (1.8.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
Gem files will remain installed in /home/dbugger/.bundler/tmp/24874/gems/ffi-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dbugger/.bundler/tmp/24874/gems/ffi-1.8.1/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887816/problems-installing-ruby-gem-ffi-on-ubuntu-server-12-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9-dev`.

Then `bundle install` again.

As an aside you probably want to not mess with the system ruby and install ruby locally instead with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: what is rbenv or rvm?

Comment: They are both tools for installing and managing isolated ruby installations so that you can switch between versions. Also this frees you from messing with the system ruby which may or may not be sensitive to other programs you have running as either root or another user. They require a good understanding of linux fundamentals to know exactly what they're doing, but at the same time they're fairly easy to learn and start using quickly after reading the initial docs.